# Connect as local on SQL Server 2005 fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 installed by another user on my system.

Now using my credentials, I am trying to use windows authentication to log into SQL Server 2005 Management Studio. I enter the credentials as:

```
servername : (local)
Windows Authentication
```

And I get the following error:

> login failed for user -- microsoft sql server error 18456

Is this because the SQL Server was not installed by my windows login credentials? (we have many user accounts on this system)

Should I re-install SQL Server?

Comment: Your Windows credentials obviously don't have any access to that particular server instance - there is no `Login` on that server instance for your Windows user

Comment: whats the remedy for this? Can you please tell me how to add a new server instance?

Comment: i mean, for this particular user, how do i create the server instance?

Comment: Some administrator on this server will need to **add** your Windows credentials as a `Login` to this SQL Server instance, and based on that `Login`, your DBA can create the necessary `User` objects in whatever databases you need to have access to